# What should be done first: extract snapshot or create genesis?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, genesis, bsc, binance

[bsc](/questions/tagged/bsc) [documentation](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html) describes a method of accelerating creation of a full-node using a [snapshot](https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/snapshot).

However, it is not clear in which order these commands should be executed and if it makes any difference:

```bash
geth --datadir /srv/node init genesis.json
unzip geth.zip -d /srv/node/
```

or

```bash
unzip geth.zip -d /srv/node/
geth --datadir /srv/node init genesis.json
```

It is also not clear if there are any special attributes that should be used when syncing node using snapshot.

This is what I am using at the moment:

```bash
./build/bin/geth \
  --syncmode snap \
  --config ./config.toml \
  --datadir /srv/node \
  --cache 18000 \
  # https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/03/03/geth-v1-10-0/
  --rpc.allow-unprotected-txs \
  --txlookuplimit 0 \
  --ipcpath /srv/geth.ipc
```

Answer (score 0):

I support creating the genesis file before unzipping the last known good chain data just to be sure that you have a working "empty" geth node although there is nothing that says it is should be before or after the genesis creation.

The docs say that the chain data is used to fix bad blocks or stuck nodes, which means that the genesis file is not going to get affected by the data being swapped. Another thing the docs say is that you can do the extraction in the background and immediately lunch your node and it won't crash or report failure (using the snap sync mode).

Another thing is that the dataDir you are using right now shouldn't be the same place that you would unzip your compressed data file in. the docs specify the `/node/geth` directory as the one for the unzipping and `/node` for the datadir argument.

```
unzip  /NAME_OF_YOUR_HOME/node/geth/ -f chaindata_202102.zip
geth --config ./config.toml --datadir ./node --syncmode snap
```